# Is this a valid use of polymorphism and if it is how should I declare this relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism

I have an Appointment model, which can be initialized by Tutor or Student. Once initialized by one side, the other side can accept or decline.

I design my models as: Appointment, and Participant. Participant has two attributes: participant_id and participant_type ("Tutor"/"Student"). I would like to declare Appointment has_one Tutor, has_many Students using polymorphic.

My questions are: Is this a valid use of polymorphism? If yes, then how should I declare this relationship and the foreign keys? If no, then why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Use polymorphism when you have a common property (such as the ability to participate in appointments) shared among different entities (such as Students and Tutors). I think your situation calls for polymorphism for Participants, rather than Appointments.

Ask yourself: are there different types of Appointments, or different types of Participants? From the information you've provided, it seems like you have one kind of Appointment, and different kinds of Participants.

#### An example of polymorphic Participant

**Appointment**

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participants
  has_one  :tutor,    :through => participants
  has_many :students, :through => participants
end
```

**Student**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments, :as => appointable
end
```

**Tutor**

```
class Tutor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments, :as => :appointable
end
```

**Participant**

```
# This model joins your appointable entities (Tutors and Students)
# to Appointments
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :appointment
  belongs_to :appointable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

As far as declaring your foreign keys goes, Rails takes care of that for you.

**Migration for Participant**

```
class CreateParticipants < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :partipants do |t| 
      t.references :appointment
      t.references :appointable, :polymorphic => true
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :participants
  end
end
```

For a better understanding of how Rails translates keywords such as `polymorphic` into SQL associations, see the guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

I think state machines are an interesting option - I don't have experience with any of the Ruby/Rails state machine projects, so I can't give you advice on that.

#### Scheduling

This is an incomplete picture of how to set up scheduling. Hopefully, it should be enough to get you started.

Add these methods to Appointment:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Anybody may request a new appointment,
  # specifying the initiator, and other participants
  # they would like to attend.
  def self.request requester, requested_participants=nil
    a = self.new
    a.status = "requested"
    a.requester = requester
    a.request_participation_of requested_participants
    a.save!
  end

  # Anybody may call this method
  # to request that the appointment be 
  # rescheduled, specifying the requester
  def reschedule requester
    self.status = "reschedule_requested"
    requester.participation_in(self).update_attribute :status=> "requester_of_reschedule"
    self.participants.where("appointable_id != ?", requester.id)
      .update_all :status => "reschedule_requested"
    self.save!
  end

  protected

  def requester= requester
    requester.participation_in(self).update_attribute :status => "requester"
  end

  def request_participation_of participants
    if participants.is_a? Array
      participants.each do |participant|
        participant.request_participation_in self
      end
    else
      request_participation_of [participants]
    end
  end
end
```

The Scheduling module contains methods for Tutors and Students, so you can do things like `student_3.request_appointment tutor_1` or `tutor_1.reschedule_appointment appointment_4`.

`lib/appointments/scheduling.rb`:

```
module Appointments::Scheduling
  # When a Student or Tutor's participation
  # in an Appointment has been requested,
  # he/she indicates acceptance of the request
  # with this method
  def accept_participation_in appointment
    self.participation_in(appointment).update_attribute :status => "accepted"
  end

  # Same as above, to decline the request
  def decline_participation_in appointment
    self.participation_in(appointment).update_attribute :status => "declined"
  end

  # This method finds the Student or Tutor's
  # Participant object for a particular Appointment
  def participation_in appointment
    Participant.where(:appointment_id => appointment.id)
      .find_by_appointable_id self.id
  end

  # A student or tutor can request a new
  # Appointment with a participant or
  # group of participants with this method
  def request_appointment participants
    Appointment.request self, participants
  end

  # This Student or Tutor's participation
  # in an appointment can be requested with
  # this method
  def request_participation_in appointment
    Participant.find_or_create_by_appointment_id_and_appointable_id(
      :appointment_id => appointment.id,
      :appointable_id => self.id
    )
  end

  # This Student or Tutor's confirmation of
  # a scheduled Appointment may be requested
  # with this method
  def request_reschedule_of appointment
    new_status = "reschedule_requested"
    if participant.id.eql? requester.id
      new_status = "requester_of_reschedule"
    end
    self.participation_in(appointment).update_attribute :status => new_status
  end

  # A Student or Tutor may reschedule a
  # particular Appointment with this method
  def reschedule_appointment appointment
    appointment.reschedule self
  end
end
```

Once these modules are in place, you can include them in the appropriate entities:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Appointments::Schedulable
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Appointments::Scheduling
end

class Tutor < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Appointments::Scheduling
end
```

My example also requires that you add a `status` field to both Appointment and Participant. I would eventually create an AppointmentStatus and a ParticipantStatus - first I would get the system working without that, however.

Here is a helpful resource on creating modules for use in your models: http://henrik.nyh.se/2008/02/rails-model-extensions

Comment: Thanks a bunch for a great answer! Please do advice on how to model initialization etc. I was thinking about state machine on Appointment. But since I have accept/decline/reschedule actions that logically belong to participants, I am not sure how to design this.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that in my case I don't need polymorphism. Instead, I need conditional active relation:

Appointment.rb

```
 has_one :tutor, :class_name => "Participant", :foreign_key => :appointment_id, :conditions => {:invitable_type => "Tutor"},  :dependent => :destroy
```

Comment: In this case, Tutor is still a type of participant, and is not directly referenced by Appointment. So you'll either need Polymorphism (as I demonstrated in my answer) or Single Table Inheritance (where the Tutor model descends from the Participant model).

Comment: Hi Max, I think if I add a type column to Participant and use :conditions => {:type => "Tutor"}, then I can referenced Participant directly from Event. Am I right?

Comment: That is correct. I shouldn't have used the words "directly referenced". What you are thinking of is Single Table Inheritance: you will end up declaring `Tutor < Participant` and `Student < Participant`. My two cents: STI an appropriate approach if your Tutor and your Student use mostly the same attributes. If the two are very different, Single Table Inheritance will become unwieldy, and Polymorphism will be a better choice.